# Make a keyboard shortcut do something on two presses

Tags: emacs, elisp

In Emacs, I want to make a keyboard combination do one thing if I press it once, and another thing if I press it twice. Beyond that I don't care (probably alternating would make the most sense). I know how to make something alternate, but the thing is, I want it to reset whenever I do something else, so that pressing the shortcut once, moving the cursor, and then pressing it again does the pressing once action, not the pressing twice action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `last-command`, for example

```lisp
(defun eab/etags-find-or-pop ()
  (interactive)
  (if (memq last-command '(eab/etags-find-or-pop))
      (call-interactively 'pop-tag-mark)
    (call-interactively 'etags-select-find-tag-at-point)))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-.") 'eab/etags-find-or-pop)
```

If you press `M-.` fisrt time, it calls one thing, and if `M-. M-.` (second time) it calls another thing.

Comment: Thanks. In case you're wondering what I used it for: https://github.com/asmeurer/dotfiles/commit/91ae190e5f1647688947ac2ebb36a3905e64d53e

Comment: I guess to make it alternate, you could define some boolean variable for the first part of the if, and then for the else part, do one thing if it is true and the other if it is false, flipping it each time.

Comment: Yes. In my case it doesn't switch the behaviour, it continues to call "another thing`. (e.g. for `M-. M-. M-.`, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to test this kind of repetition is with `(eq this-command last-command)`.